# Can I set Windows console position programmatically?

Tags: c, cmd, console, position

Thanks to Google, I know I can use third party apps like `nircmd` or `cmdow` to tweak my windows positions but I was wondering if there is any chance to achieve the same thing with Windows default `cmd` tool.

I am writing a simple C code which runs two executable in two separate windows. This is how I launch my two applications in parallel:

```
int main (void)
{
   system("cmd /c start app1");
   system("cmd /c start app2");
}
```

The thing is they both open at the same position and sit on top of each other making me to manually move one of them.

Is there any chance I could set the their positions though my code?

For the sake of more clarity, I am using CygWin on Windows.

Comment: You could use `FindWindow` to get the window handle of the console, and then `SetWindowPos`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  There are at least two ways that I can think of right now.

One is a bit difficult: you have to use Win32 calls to programmatically find their windows and move them to the positions you want.  I don't suppose you want to do that, so forget it.

Another way is to do the following:

```
system("cmd /c start \"a\" app1");
system("cmd /c start \"b\" app1");
```

and then go to `\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\a` and `\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\b` and create values for `WindowSize` and `WindowPosition` like the ones you will find in `\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

(Note that in order for the `WindowPosition` value to be created in `\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` you have to first uncheck the "let windows choose the window position" checkbox in the layout tab of the options dialog of the command prompt.)

Comment: Thanks Mike but this approach is not portable. Right? Still there is some setup involved. Unless you tell me that I could set all those registry changes via my code (I highly doubt it)

Comment: @Bababarghi You could set all of those registry values with straight C using the WinAPI, but you kind of throw out portability when you `#include <Windows.h>`

Comment: From the moment you are invoking `cmd.exe` you are by definition not portable, so perhaps "portable" was not the word you were looking for. If you want to avoid the setup, you can of course set the registry values programmatically.  Look at this reference: [MSDN - RegSetValueEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then search for sample code involving this function call.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is probably to find each of your console windows' handles with [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then set their position with [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
     /* start your applications with known window titles */

     HWND handle1 = FindWindow(NULL, "Console Window 1's Title");
     HWND handle2 = FindWindow(NULL, "Console Window 2's Title");

     SetWindowPos(handle1, NULL, newX1, newY1, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
     SetWindowPos(handle2, NULL, newX2, newY2, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}
```

Comment: Is the fact that I am using CygWin on Windows, the reason I can't use your mentioned approach? The code seems not to recognise `FindWindow`

Comment: @Bababarghi Hmm... that's curious. I originally used Visual Studio to compile the code, but I just tried it with gcc on cygwin with no problems.

Comment: @Bababarghi It just occurred to me that you might need Visual Studio installed to actually access the Windows API (with Windows.h).  If you can, you might want to install VS2015 Community (its free, and it's the best IDE for C/C++ Windows development IMO) https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: folks, someone else has suggested using `ShellReturn = (int)ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "app1.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` Is that true?

Comment: @Bababarghi Do you mean to start your app? `ShellExecute` doesn't change the window position.

Comment: Well, that was the idea to both run and set the position. By the sound of it, it's not the case. Tnx anyway.

Comment: @Bababarghi Why did you unaccept this answer? Was there something that I left out?

Comment: well it looks neat but I couldn't get it working unfortunately

Comment: described in first comment. CygWin complains about unknown command and the solution you suggested about installing VS2015 is simply not possible on this specific machine. It's a uni pc with restricted permissions for installing new applications

Comment: @Bababarghi I installed cygwin on one of my PCs without Visual Studio, but I wasn't able to recreate your problem. I'm not sure what the issue is.